# Ban Keywords FreeForm Pro + AJAX Submit not working

Tags: solspace-freeform, ajax

I have a couple of 'ban keywords' set to try and minimise spam in a FreeForm Pro form. The form is inline validated and submitted via ajax/jquery.
In the js code, I'm checking for data.seccess = true.
However, even if I put some banned keywords in the form, I still get success=true and the form submits..
What can I do to make the form not submit when banned keywords are used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had contact with Solspace about this and after testing the form without AJAX the page through an error complaining about the an invalid regex match.
In my banned keyword list there was an html "a" closing tag that was causing the error.
So, you can only use normal words in the ban keyword field; no special characters.